# How to configure Ubuntu so that it can access roaming / home folder / folder redirection

Tags: server

I have Windows Server with Roaming / Work / Home Folders + Folder Redirection Configured.
I want to configure Ubuntu for roaming + work + home folder as folder Redirection from Windows Server.

Comment: What’s your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Do you mean you want to mount Windows shared filesystems? Or have 3 different user profiles on Ubuntu? Or what? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask